# Invalid JSON character: "" at 0:0. when running command "ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli-v6

I have cloned a project from **github** and am trying to run it locally, it seems that the .`angular-cli.json` file needs to be updated, I have ran through some of the tutorials here on how to do that and am faced with this **error**.

> ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
>               Updating karma configuration
>               Updating configuration
>               Removing old config file (.angular-cli.json)
>               Writing config file (angular.json) Invalid JSON character: "" at 0:0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to upgrade angular core version for your cloned project. Any way this error happens due to json files **wrong encoding** so you must ensure that all your json files like **(angular-cli.json, tslint.json and tsconfig.json) are UTF-8 encoded not UTF With BOM**.
You can change encoding of these files using **VSCode or notepad++** so running ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4 should wrong smoothly without any problems

Comment: I renamed tsconfig.json & angular-cli.json and then created new ones / copied and pasted. Then it worked!

Comment: UTF-8 update alone fixed it for me for all listed files by Ramy.

Answer (score 4):

Fix this issue with visual studio code, you can change the encoding with Visual studio code see the steps below
[image]

Comment: what all files need to do this?